# How to parse filepaths in PowerShell-Functions the correct way?

Tags: powershell, path, powershell-cmdlet

I have written functions that have path parameters.
I'm not sure if I implemented it correctly. Is there a standardized or better way of doing this in Powershell?

```
function Get-PathExample {
  param(
    [Parameter(Position=0,mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="Profilepath e.g. C:\Users or \\computername\c$\users\")]
    [string]$ProfilePath,

    [Parameter(Position=1,mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="SubPath e.g. AppData\Roaming\")]
    [string]$SubPath
  )

  <#
    code...
  #>
}
```

Comment: That depends on what you want to use them for. Accepting strings from the caller (as you do here) and then resolving + validating the paths inside the function is usually the correct approach. But if `$ProfilePath` and `$SubPath` are meant to form a single continuous path stem - then why not just accept a single `[string]$Path` with the full path? What problem are you trying to solve by accepting it in two parts?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen e.g. one of my functions does calculate the foldersize of subpaths from **multiple userprofiles**. I use `Resolving-Path` for both strings. Then I combine `$ProfilePath`with a `* wildcard` and SubPath using `Join-Path` inside a `GCI-Command`. This does work fine. I'm just wondering if that is the correct way. Does Microsoft implement paths in their own cmdlets in a similar way?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen  And what is the best way for validating? Check it with a regex-pattern?

Comment: `Resolve-Path` is the right way, for additional validation you may test the `Provider` attached to its output to ensure it's a file system path, eg. `$resolved = Resolve-Path $path |Where-Object { $_.Provider.Name -eq 'FileSystem'}`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen The hint with `Provider` is very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your basic approach is correct - accept path stems as string arguments, then resolve and validate inside the function.

You can add the most basic level of input validation to the `param` block itself - like validating that the `$ProfilePath` only resolves to *directories* for example:

```
param(
  [Parameter(...)]
  # Any path that doesn't exclusively resolve to 1 or more
  # directories will now cause a parameter validation error
  [ValidateScript({ Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType Container })]
  [string]$ProfilePath,

  ...
)
```

Then inside the function you can perform more domain-specific validation - like testing that the resolved paths are indeed *filesystem* paths:

```
foreach ($resolvedPath in Resolve-Path -Path $ProfilePath) {
  if ($resolvedPath.Provider.Name -ne 'FileSystem') {
    Write-Warning "Resolved non-filesystem item at $($resolvedPath.Path), skipping entry"
    continue
  }

  # work with $resolvedPath.Path here (or store it for later)
}
```

---

In the most basic scenarios - where you don't need to care about the paths themselves, but just want to resolve 1 or more provider items from a caller-supplied path - a better option is to mimic the parameter surface of the corresponding provider cmdlet (like `Get-Item`) and then just offload all the heavy lifting to that command instead.

To do that, use the following to generate the source code for a new parameter blocks:

```
# locate the provider cmdlet we want to mimic
$targetCommand = Get-Command Get-Item

# create CommandMetadata object from command info
$commandMetadata = [System.Management.Automation.CommandMetadata]::new($targetCommand)

# generate new proxy param block from Get-Item
$paramBlock = [System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::GetParamBlock($commandMetadata)
```

On Windows you can copy the resulting code to your clipboard with `$paramBlock |Set-ClipBoard`

The result will look like this:

```
[Parameter(ParameterSetName='Path', Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
[string[]]
${Path},

[Parameter(ParameterSetName='LiteralPath', Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
[Alias('PSPath')]
[string[]]
${LiteralPath},

[string]
${Filter},

[string[]]
${Include},

[string[]]
${Exclude},

[switch]
${Force},

[Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
[pscredential]
[System.Management.Automation.CredentialAttribute()]
${Credential}
```

Now manually remove the parameter definitions related to features you don't need, and you might end up with something like:

```
[Parameter(ParameterSetName='Path', Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
[string[]]
${Path},

[Parameter(ParameterSetName='LiteralPath', Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
[Alias('PSPath')]
[string[]]
${LiteralPath},

[switch]
${Force}
```

Replace the contents of your param block with the above and add a `[CmdletBinding()]` decorator to set the default parameter set to the `$Path` one:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'Path')]
param(
  <# generated parameter definitions from above go here #>
)
```

... at which point you can just pass the caller's parameter arguments off to `Get-Item` as-is:

```
foreach ($item in Get-Item @PSBoundParameters) {
  # work with $item 
}
```

Now the caller can supply either wildcard paths or exact paths as they see fit, and `Get-Item` takes care of the rest

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Very detailed. Thank you!